# Does R have something similar to TransformedDistribution in Mathematica?

Tags: r, wolfram-mathematica, probability

I have a random variable `X` and a transformation `f` and I would like to know the probability distribution function of `f(X)`, at least approximately. In Mathematica there is TransformedDistribution, but I could not find something similar in R. As I said, some kind of approximative solution would be fine, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the `distr` package. For instance, say that `y = x^2+2x+1`, where `x` is normally distributed with mean 2 and standard deviation 5. You can:

```
require(distr)
x<-Norm(2,5)
y<-x^2+2*x+1
#y@r gives random samples. We make an histogram.
hist(y@r(10000))
#y@d and y@p are the density and the cumulative functions
y@d(80)
#[1] 0.002452403
y@p(80)
#[1] 0.8891796
```

Comment: looks good. But I get y@p(-1) = 0.08723655 which is weird since y should never be negative...

Comment: I went over into this and it looks like that the expression `x^2+2*x+1` is interpreted as the sum of *independent* random variables, i.e. the `x^2` part and the `2*x` part are taken separately. If you define `y<-(x+1)^2`, you get the correct behavior. Guess this needs `distr` maintainer's attention.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for all the work. Notwithstanding the bug, this is precisely what I was looking for.

Comment: Actually, if you look at `distrARITH()`, this issue is discussed. So it's the intended behavior (look at `Multiple instances in expressions and independence` section).